# Unity : Initial Speed for the player car

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I’m working in  [Racing Game Kit Pro source](http://unityracingkit.com/) and i want to make the player car to walk automatically when the race start the player just turn right , left or speed but the vehicle never stop .
I tried to do it but i cannot make it . i need  solution for it

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What did you try to do exactly?

Comment: i try to make it change the position of it through the transform.postion in update to change the z direction but not applied to it although this function applied in any object , but i think that is another solution better than this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the "Racing Game Kit Pro" but when I did a racing game whit a self written driving script there was a variable named "speed" which showed me the actual Speed of the Car.
But I also could enter a value.

Anyway you might wan't something with two variables like:

(just an example "Code" doesn't work)

basic speed = 100 km/h
actual speed = basic speed + Input.GetAxis (Long time since I did something like that not sure if it is right :P)

At the moment I'm at school but if you want I can see if I still have the driving script so if you're interested just PM me :)

Hope I could Help